Android security error No installed provider supports
I use certificate for network requests.
val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
keyStore.load(caFileInputStream, certPassword.toCharArray()) 

When i run the app with obfuscation on some devices i get exception
error constructing MAC: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.PKCS12Key

I checked if the system has such provider:
Security.getProviders()

and i see the provider
name =BC;
info = BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.68;
class = com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
My system env:
compileSdk 34
targetSdkVersion 34
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
I tried to add classes to proguard like this
-keep class java.security.**{ *; }
#-keep class com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.PKCS12Key
-keep class com.android.org.bouncycastle.** { *; } 

Still doesn't work. I see one strange thing. The error say i don't have provider
com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.PKCS12Key
but exist provider has class path
com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
Is this system error? Can this be fixed on my end?
I know how to make it work, but I'm not sure if this solution won't create new problems
I have added link to Bounce lib to the project
implementation("org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15to18:1.74")

Now i have two BouncyCastleProvider. one built in
***com.android.***org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
and another one from the lib
***org.bouncycastle.***jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
as i see the differences between them is:
built in - BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.68
lib - BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.74
when I use BouncyCastleProvider from the library everything works without exception
Note:
If you use obfuscation have to add
-keep class org.bouncycastle.jce.**{*;}
to progourd.

Didn't had older Android versions their own Bouncy castle version included? May be those devices are affected as the classes from APK collide with system classes (that was the reason Spongy castle existed). You should get more details on the affected devices. Also consider if Bouncycastle is needed at all for loading a PKCS#12 file. The default implementation of Android is not sufficient?

that is the problem. i did not add the Bounce lib to the project. It's built in.
KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
That method has two implementation. This one means: i asked the system to find needed provider for PKCS12. and i get exception.

BouncyCastleProvider sometimes needs to load org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.**.
So you need to add
-keep class org.bouncycastle.** {*;}

to ProGuard.
